# How to center object in galleria slider

Tags: jquery, css, galleria

I am using Galleria plugin but what I want to do is center the main object which is the audio player inside the galleria slider. But how can I do this?

Below is basic galleria style:

```
<style>
    #galleriaaudio_<?php echo $key; ?>{ width: 550px; height: 200px; background: #000; }
</style>
```

I have demo application page here: [DEMO](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/Text44.php)

UPDATE:

Below is current code where try to pick each specific audio player in slider and center it:

```
<?php

                          $j = 0;

        ?>

    <style>
        #galleriaaudio_<?php echo $key; ?>{ width: 550px; height: 200px; background: #000; margin:0; }
    </style>

     <div id="galleriaaudio_<?php echo $key; ?>">
    <?php
    foreach ($arrAudioFile[$key] as $a) { ?>

    <a href="audio.php?key=<?php echo $key; ?>&j=<?php echo $j; ?>&a=<?php echo $a; ?>"><img class="iframe" src="Images/audiothumbnail.png"></a>

    <?php $j++; ?>
    <?php } ?>
    </div><br/>

             <script type="text/javascript">

                          $(window).load(function(){
       var key = '<?php echo $key; ?>';
       var j = '<?php echo $j; ?>';
        $("#galleriaaudio_"+key)
            .find("iframe")
            .contents()
            .find("#jp_container_"+key+"-"+j)
            .attr('style', 'margin: 0 auto');
        });

                Galleria.loadTheme('jquery/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');
                Galleria.run('#galleriaaudio_<?php echo $key; ?>');

              </script> 

Below is releavt divs belonging to each audio player which gives each audio player uniqueness:

      <div id="jquery_jplayer-<?php echo $key.'-'.$j; ?>" class="jp-jplayer"></div>
      <div id="jp_container_<?php echo $key.'-'.$j; ?>" class="jp-audio">
```

Comment: can you please show the example in jsfiddle?

Comment: @DebasishChowdhury It will be hard for me to produce a fiddle ecause majority is php coded but I have created a demo so you can see what it looks like. The reason I want the audio player to be centered in the slider beause you won't be able to press the play button as the slider arrow is in the way

Comment: @Manixman please have look on my answer and try the solution and let me know if i am lagging some where.

Answer (score 7):

You can try use below css for problem.

**CSS:**

File: http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/jquery/skin/jplayer.blue.monday.css

Line: 33

```
div.jp-audio {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 420px;
}
```

**Screen shot:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use for any particular item, use this,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var key = '<?php echo $key; ?>';
    $("#galleriaaudio_"+key)
        .find("iframe")
        .contents()
        .find("#jp_container_"+key+"-0")
        .attr('style', 'margin: 0 auto');
 });
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: The only issue I have with this is that how my full applicaton works is that I have an assessment, an assessment obviously contains questions, for each question, if there is no audio file, then do not display an audio player, if there is a single audo file then display a single audio player on the page, if there are multiple audio files then display the audio players into the slider. The issue I have if I change the code you mentioned directly is that it will center the single audio player on the page as well as the audio player in the slider. I only want the audio player in slider to center.

Comment: Good idea but did not work, I tried changing it to `.find("#jp_container_"+key+"-"+j)` as well, `var j = '<?php echo $j; ?>';` but still does not center it

Comment: Can you upload the changes in your demo?

Comment: in your code you set J = 3, but the div id i can see, is "jp_container_7-0", so "J" should be 0. Also, better you try $(window).load() instead of $(document).ready(). Because, $(window).load() will do it's work after galleria complete it's own work, i.e creating iframe etc.

Comment: Error in syntax ... in your demo page ... $(window).load() not written properly

Comment: Sorry bout that, have a look at demo again. Strangley enough it is not centering now

Answer (score 0):

Easily with CSS (using your existing ID structure):

```
#js { text-align: center; }
div.jp-audio { margin: 15px auto 0 auto; }
```

This will also stay fluid in case the width of your enclosing `div` changes

Answer (score 0):

In http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/jquery/skin/jplayer.blue.monday.css , change this:

```
div.jp-audio {
    width:420px;
}
```

to

```
div.jp-audio {
    width:420px;
        margin:0 auto;
}
```

Margin 0 auto is often used to center elements "the correct way".

Answer (score -1):

add `margin:0 auto;` to `div.jp-audio` in jplayer.blue.monday.css file on line no 33